# How to gather personal information (age,gender..) of all the authors of the comments on a specific video, with Python YouTube API

Tags: python, youtube-api

I'm using YouTube API with Python. I can already gather all the comments of a specific video, including the name of the authors, the date and the content of the comments.
I can also with a separate piece of code, extract the personal information (age,gender,interests,...) of a specific author. 
But I can not use them in one place. i.e. I need to gather all the comments of a video, with the name of the comments' authors and having the personal information of all those authors. 
in follow is the code that I developed. But I get an 'RequestError' which I dont know how to handle and where is the problem.

```
 import gdata.youtube
import gdata.youtube.service

yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
f = open('test1.csv','w')
f.writelines(['UserName',',','Age',',','Date',',','Comment','\n'])

def GetAndPrintVideoFeed(string1):

        yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
        user_entry = yt_service.GetYouTubeUserEntry(username = string1)
        X = PrintentryEntry(user_entry)
        return X

def PrintentryEntry(entry):

        # print required fields where we know there will be information
        Y = entry.age.text
        return Y

def GetComment(next1):

        yt_service = gdata.youtube.service.YouTubeService()
        nextPageFeed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(next1)

        for comment_entry in nextPageFeed.entry:

            string1 = comment_entry.author[0].name.text.split("/")[-1]
            Z = GetAndPrintVideoFeed(string1)
            string2 = comment_entry.updated.text.split("/")[-1]
            string3 = comment_entry.content.text.split("/")[-1]

            f.writelines( [str(string1),',',Z,',',string2,',',string3,'\n'])

        next2 = nextPageFeed.GetNextLink().href
        GetComment(next2)

video_id = '8wxOVn99FTE'
comment_feed = yt_service.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=video_id)

for comment_entry in comment_feed.entry:

        string1 = comment_entry.author[0].name.text.split("/")[-1]
        Z = GetAndPrintVideoFeed(string1)
        string2 = comment_entry.updated.text.split("/")[-1]
        string3 = comment_entry.content.text.split("/")[-1]

        f.writelines( [str(string1),',',Z,',',string2,',',string3,'\n'])

next1 = comment_feed.GetNextLink().href
GetComment(next1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need a better understanding of the Youtube API and how everything relates together.  I've written wrapper classes which can handle multiple types of Feeds or Entries and "fixes" gdata's inconsistent parameter conventions.

Here are some snippets showing how the scraping/crawling can be generalized without too much difficulty.

I know this isn't directly answering your question, It's more high level design but it's worth thinking about if you're going to be doing a large amount of youtube/gdata data pulling.

```
def get_feed(thing=None, feed_type=api.GetYouTubeUserFeed):

    if feed_type == 'user':
        feed = api.GetYouTubeUserFeed(username=thing)

    if feed_type == 'related':
        feed = api.GetYouTubeRelatedFeed(video_id=thing)

    if feed_type == 'comments':
        feed = api.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed(video_id=thing)

    feeds = []
    entries = []

    while feed:
        feeds.append(feed)
        feed = api.GetNext(feed)

    [entries.extend(f.entry) for f in feeds]

    return entries
```

...

```
def myget(url,service=None):

    def myconverter(x):
        logfile = url.replace('/',':')+'.log'
        logfile = logfile[len('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/'):]
        my_logger.info("myget: %s" % url)

        if service == 'user_feed':
            return gdata.youtube.YouTubeUserFeedFromString(x)

        if service == 'comment_feed':
            return gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoCommentFeedFromString(x)

        if service == 'comment_entry':
            return gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoCommentEntryFromString(x)

        if service == 'video_feed':
            return gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoFeedFromString(x)

        if service == 'video_entry':
            return gdata.youtube.YouTubeVideoEntryFromString(x)


    return api.GetWithRetries(url,
            converter=myconverter,
            num_retries=3,
            delay=2,
            backoff=5,
            logger=my_logger
            )


mapper={}
mapper[api.GetYouTubeUserFeed]='user_feed'
mapper[api.GetYouTubeVideoFeed]='video_feed'
mapper[api.GetYouTubeVideoCommentFeed]='comment_feed'
```

https://gist.github.com/2303769 data/service.py (routing)